# how to write to many output types from one input type?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am a newbie to kafka streams.

I am able to achieve the following.
I have an input topic. The message object (say Flower).
I have a transformer that converts Flower into Fruit.
I then store the Fruit to output topic.

What I want to achieve is like something that follows

1. I store Fruit to Fruit topic (... as above)
2. I store (the successful) Flower to Successful_Flower topic (... additionally)

(If it is not possible to discriminate Flowers as above, it is even okay if I can store the incoming Flower (successful or failed ...both) to OutputFlower topic)

Is this possible? If yes, how?
Please let me know if I need to supply more details.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use the method `branch` as follow:

```
    KStream<String, Either<Flower, Fruit>>[] flowerAndFruitStreams = inputMessages
            .flatMapValues(flower -> List.<Either<Flower, Fruit>>of(Either.left(flower), Either.right(fromFlowerToFruit(flower)))) 
            .branch((key, value) -> value.isLeft(), (key, value) -> value.isRight());

    KStream<String, Either<Flower, Fruit>> flowerStream = flowerAndFruitStreams[0];
    KStream<String, Either<Flower, Fruit>> fruitsStream = flowerAndFruitStreams[1];
```

**Explanations**

As you can see, the branch method returns a `KStream<K, V>[]` which means that the input is split in many streams based on the predicates applied to this method. Because of this, after you convert a flower to fruit you should return an object which either contains the flower, either the fruit so that to have a stream of the same objects type. For this we will borrow from functional programming the concept of `Either` which you can find it below:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Either<L, R> {

    private final Optional<L> left;
    private final Optional<R> right;

    private Either(Optional<L> l, Optional<R> r) {
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }

    public static <L, R> Either<L, R> left(L value) {
        return new Either<>(Optional.of(value), Optional.empty());
    }

    public static <L, R> Either<L, R> right(R value) {
        return new Either<>(Optional.empty(), Optional.of(value));
    }

    public boolean isLeft() {
        return left.isPresent();
    }

    public boolean isRight() {
        return right.isPresent();
    }

    public L getLeft() {
        return left.get();
    }

    public R getRight() {
        return right.get();
    }

    public <T> T map(Function<? super L, ? extends T> leftFunc, Function<? super R, ? extends T> rightFunc) {
        return left.<T>map(leftFunc).orElseGet(() -> right.map(rightFunc).get());
    }

    public <T> Either<T, R> mapLeft(Function<? super L, ? extends T> leftFunc) {
        return new Either<>(left.map(leftFunc), right);
    }

    public <T> Either<L, T> mapRight(Function<? super R, ? extends T> rightFunc) {
        return new Either<>(left, right.map(rightFunc));
    }

    public void apply(Consumer<? super L> leftFunc, Consumer<? super R> rightFunc) {
        left.ifPresent(leftFunc);
        right.ifPresent(rightFunc);
    }
}
```

I didn't compiled the code, so please double check the syntax. This code is based on Java 13 and KafkaStreams 2.5.0 but should work also for newest versions.